# How can an iFrame that has content, have an undefined contentDocument object?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension, disqus

I've been trying to develop a browser extension that needs to inject event handlers into all iFrames on a page. I have found that some iFrames, like those used for the Disqus commenting system, have content but no contentDocument.

How is this possible, and how can I access the event handlers for an iframe without a contentDocument?

Check out the comment section at the bottom of [this](http://stephenturley.com/Blog/Details/5) page for an example. If you inspect the comment text area, you will see it is in an iFrame that has no contentDocument.

Comment: I've done some more research and it seems like this may be a security feature. Since the Disqus comment box is from another domain, it prevents my content script from accessing its elements. This is just a theory, but I'm confused because if i set "all_frames" : true, the script will inject into the frame just fine. But I don't need the entire script, just two event handlers.

Comment: Yes, the same-domain policy means you have no access to the iFrame contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by [Same-Origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)