# Post to iframe target: cannot get response from iframe

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe

I have a bookmarklet. When it is clicked (on any page):

1. it inserts a script element with src from mypage.com. This src is downloaded.
2. The src then:

   - inserts an iframe (DOM)
   - inserts a form (DOM). The form targets the iframe.
   - Adds data to the form and submits it to mypage.com
3. mypage.com sends back a response: `<div id = "msg">Message back</div>`
4. This response div is inserted into the iframe. (verified in Chrome elements tab)
5. Now I want to alert the returned msg "Message back". It's not working.

When creating the iframe, I have set its `onload` event:

```
var i = document.createElement('iframe');
i.setAttribute('id', 'frame-id');
i.setAttribute('onload', 'iframeFormSubmitted();');
```

I then have the function:

```
function iframeFormSubmitted(){
    // in try-catch, alerting error
    var iframe = document.getElementById("frame-id");
    var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var msg = iframeDocument.getElementById("msg").innerHTML;
    alert(msg);
```

}

This ends up being called twice (first time, I think, because I also write the form to the iframe). The errors are:

```
cannot read property innerHTMl of null
cannot call method getElementById of undefined
```

Edit: contentDocument is undefined. I'm thinking it's a cross domain thing: [How can an iFrame that has content, have an undefined contentDocument object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451194/how-can-an-iframe-that-has-content-have-an-undefined-contentdocument-object)

Answer (score 2):

Create a `function` in your parent document (The document where the `iframe` lives on), for example, the function `done` in your parent document as given below

```
function done(message)
{
    // do whatever you want to do with message
    alert(message);
}
```

From the server (mypage.com) send following code to the `iframe` as a response

```
// Call the "done" function from the iframe (the last line on the server)
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>parent.done('This is my message')</script>";
```

It'll work, I've applied this heck on one my projects and working flawlessly.

Some `HTML` fragments given below from my working progect

```
<form action="someAction" method="post" id="imageform" name="imageform" target="img_submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input style="display:none" type="file" name="imgfile" id="imgfile" />
    <input style="display:none" type="submit" name="subimg" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This is the `iframe` which is hidden

```
 <iframe style="display:none" id="img_submit" name="img_submit"></iframe>`
```

And this my `done` function in the `parent` document (the same file where the `iframe` is)

```
function done(lnk)
{
    // this is being used for afile upload (ajax simulation/fake)
    loading('hide');
    document.imageform.reset();
}
```